# unable to start service of apache2

Tags: php, mysql, apache

These are the follow output streamed when I give command to restart the service of apache

```
 apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
 Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-08-08 11:14:56 IST; 42s ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Process: 3568 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=2)

Aug 08 11:14:56 Lab2-73 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Aug 08 11:14:56 Lab2-73 apache2[3568]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 46: .: Can't open /e
Aug 08 11:14:56 Lab2-73 apache2[3568]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 57: .: Can't open /e
Aug 08 11:14:56 Lab2-73 apache2[3568]: ERROR: APACHE_PID_FILE needs to be define
Aug 08 11:14:56 Lab2-73 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, cod
Aug 08 11:14:56 Lab2-73 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Aug 08 11:14:56 Lab2-73 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 08 11:14:56 Lab2-73 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result   'exit-co
```

Comment: It is probably your configurations. Edit /etc/apache2/bin/envvars and set the required variables

Comment: Might be of interest https://askubuntu.com/questions/629995/apache-not-able-to-restart

Answer (score 1):

Please check your configuration under /etc/init.d/apache2/. There migth be a misconfiguration. Have a look at [this little guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps).

If you cant find the mistake you can also reinstall apache2 but keep in mind that you will loose your whole configuration (depending on the actual configuration)

Comment: I am unable to connect to localhost in firefox as can't restart apache server